# Refresh ListView on Timer_Tick

Tags: vb.net, listview, timer, refresh

I'm updating my ListView in VB.net every 5 seconds on the timer_ticker event.

But I have a problem, I don't want the list to "blink" whenever it refreshes.

Is there a way to do this?

I filled the Listview in a function seperately but it didn't make any difference.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        FillListView()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can i see your FillListView() Code? thinking it may be in there. ( cause of the flash)

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle Please note that I am filling the listview from a datatable. I pasted my code here: http://urlpaste.com/PjnNKn9d

Comment: From what i can tell its not your code. From the Code I would assume that what you call "Flickering" is actually the `ListView` `Redrawing` the New Items you populate Every 5 seconds. In this case I would look at how to `modify the drawing routines of the listview`. The easier step would be to test and see if there are any differences from the new data vs the old. Therefor the Listview would only Redraw whenever there is updates to the list instead of EVERY 5 seconds. Also i'd add that there is always a way to do everything. This one just may not be so easy and above my head.